# Firestore: Updating different nested objects

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

My document structure:

```
candy : {
  Mars: {
    batches: {
       'aaa': { id: 'aaa', expires: 'tomorrow' },
       'bbb': { id: 'bbb', expires: 'in a week' }
    },
    category: 'Chocolate',
    name: 'Mars',
  }
},
```

and to add a new candy, `Haribo`, I would like to add it like this:

```
const name = 'Haribo';
const category = 'not-chocolate'
const batch = {
  id: 'ccc', 
  expires: 'in 2 years'
}

admin
  .firestore()
  .collection('shop')
  .doc(MY_SHOP)
  .update({
     [`candy.${name}`]: {
        name,
        category,
        [`candy.${name}.batches.${batch.id}`]: batch
     }
  });
```

However, if I do this and `Haribo` already exists and has multiple batches, then the above code will overwrite everything. Therefore I have had to split it into two different firestore calls. The first updates just the `name` and `category`, the second call updates the batches object.

Is there a way for me to update something this deep `[`candy.${name}.batches.${batch.id}`]` without overwriting existing batches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions) to read the entire document, make changes to its document structure in memory any way you like (add/remove/update any fields or nested maps), then write the entire document back at the end of the transaction.

It might even be better to store each batch (and even each candy) as its own document in a subcollection to make this easier, and increase your options for querying the data in the individual batches.

Comment: Thanks. If I had a document for each batch, then when i add 5 new batches, won't that count as 5x database writes? Is that a bad thing? Thanks again

Comment: If you have a new question, please post it separately along with the code you're working with and the behevior you're not certain about.

Comment: ...why...it's a question about your answer...?!

Comment: Stack Overflow has a policy of one question per post.  It's more helpful to others in the future if there is a separate post for separate questions, so the information is not buried in comments.   Please post a new question and outline the scenario of your new question.

Comment: So I copy my original question, then your answer, then my question from your answer in a new question? I'm surprised you don't see the inefficiency...